# How to securely protect my offline windows store app credentials?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I,m doing windows store offline application, for some reason I needed to store my app's clientid and secretid in app, so how to securely protect them against attacks like reverse engineering etc ,Please notice that i am not taking this values from user input, i need to use these values in c# code

Answer (score 3):

In WinRT, the best choice is to add a [`PasswordCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.aspx) to the [`PasswordVault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx).

```
var vault = new PasswordVault();

var credential = new PasswordCredential("yourapp", "clientid", "secretid");
vault.Add(credential);

// Later
credential = vault.Retrieve("yourapp", "clientid");
credential.RetrievePassword();
string password = credential.Password;
```

Comment: where i should use this code,if i use this in appconfig.cs or anywhere,if that file is reverse engineered  here in this code "var credential = new PasswordCredential("yourapp", "clientid", "secretid");" will this plain text is visible?

Comment: I assumed you were collecting the credentials from the user. If you ship the credentials with the app, you're pretty much out of luck. You could encrypt the credentials and store them in the app as a byte array, but if your app can decrypt it then a hacker can too.

Comment: yes my app shoud decrypt it,is there any possible solution can you provide?

Comment: Take a look at `Windows.Security.Cryptography` but as mentioned above, there's nothing you can do to prevent bad people from obtaining it. Your app runs on their machine; they are admin on their own machine.